# Access toolbar in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Toolbar is in mainactivity layout. So I have 3 fragments.

In main activity

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

In first fragment i just write this.

```
Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("AA");
```

In second fragment i just write this.

```
Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("BB");
```

It works fine in the beginning. I mean when i open the app, there is a "AA" in the toolbar. Thats what i want. And when i get to the second fragment there is a "BB" in the toolbar. But when i get back to the first fragment, "BB" text stays. its not updating itself. I dont know why. Can you help me? What should i write to the fragment class for accessing to toolbar where is in mainactivity.

Comment: Try to put this code in `onResume` callback of the fragments

Comment: @Zain thank u very much. I didn't notice that i should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the the fragment you set the toolbar title in `onCreateView()` and when you return back the `onCreateView()` won't get called, probably that the fragment tries to keep its state, so you need to transfer the code to the `onResume()` instead.